# How to integrate tab host with zxing qr code scanner?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, qr-code, zxing, android-tabactivity

I want to integrate zxing qr code scanner in my application which is having three tabs in my application.

Currently when my one of the tab bar butto gets pressed at that time I am calling zxing qr code's scann activity but when ever its calling it is showing error like below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.beepz/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
```

Rather my code is having both tab host control and I have instantiated tab host in my activity call as shown below.

XML File (Capture.xml) :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

      <com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView
            android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent" />
    
    </SurfaceView>
</FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

Java file : (CaptureActivity.java)

```
public final class CaptureActivity extends TabActivity implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private TabHost tabHost;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.capture);

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, first.class);      
    TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab").setIndicator("First Tab",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconinfo)).setContent(intent); 
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Do I need to change any thing in manifest file or anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

At last I solved my problem; the problem was there was a CaptureActivity.java file in my main project. And problem solved by adding TabHost in the main project's CaptureActivity.java file.