# How to change the Camera Screen in QR Code Scanner in Android?

Tags: android, qr-code

I am developing a QR Code Scanner in Android. My code for scanning QR Code works fine. However, I'd like to change the **Camera Screen** in my app.

Instead of my camera is in fullscreen mode, I'd like to make it like this:

[image]

Can someone knows how to do it?

Comment: I'm using a similar view and helped me with creating a foreground image with a transparent rect in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add a layer on top of the camera. To do this, please read the following question and answers: [Custom camera android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543244/custom-camera-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding tab host in frame layout and then set qr code camera into frame layout, by this way you can do it successfully.

You can refer following link to solve your issue.

[Custom camera screen with QR code scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370670/how-to-integrate-tab-host-with-zxing-qr-code-scanner)